# Convert list of list of integers into a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings:

```
['[2, 8]', '[8, 2]', '[2, 5, 3]', '[2, 5, 3, 0]', '[5, 3, 0, 2]']
```

I want output to look like

```
['28','82','253',2530',5302']
```

I've tried using

```
string1= ''.join(str(e) for e in list[0])
```

I get output for print (string1) as:

```
[2, 8]
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `['[2, 8]', '[8, 2]', '[2, 5, 3]', '[2, 5, 3, 0]', '[5, 3, 0, 2]']` is not a list of lists. It's a list of strings.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo, yes. I forgot that i had changed the append from list to string. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't have a `list` of `list`, you have a `list` of `str`. Therefore you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to interpret each string as a list, then convert to `str` and `join`.

```
>>> l = ['[2, 8]', '[8, 2]', '[2, 5, 3]', '[2, 5, 3, 0]', '[5, 3, 0, 2]']
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> [''.join(str(j) for j in literal_eval(i)) for i in l]
['28', '82', '253', '2530', '5302']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use built-in functions only (without imports), you can define a function that parses only the numbers and map that function to your list.

```
def remove_non_digits(z):
    return "".join(k if k.isdigit() else "" for k in z)

>>> map(remove_non_digits, a)
['28', '82', '253', '2530', '5302']
```

Comment: note that for python3, you have to cast to `list` since `map` doesn't generate one.